# Modify default user groups

Tags: 20.04, users, default, groups

Is there a way to modify the default user groups in Ubuntu 20.04? I mean if a user logs in for the first time (or if a user is created), he is automatically added to groups X, Y and Z for example.
What I want to achieve is the following: I have several Ubuntu machines that are joined to a Windows Active Directory, I want users that login on a machine with their AD credentials to be added to groups like `lpadmin`

Comment: Explain why you would want that. Explain what you really want to achieve (your problem X). Nothing is worse than being presented with a problem (Y) that *you* think is the solution to solve your real problem, X.

Comment: question has been modified.

Comment: Much better: now people see that you want a specific user group added by default, and see you have a good reason to want that.

Answer (score 0):

A range of default settings for newly created users are defined in `/etc/adduser.conf`. In Ubuntu, a directive to define which groups a new user should be assigned to is illustrating the system default settings, but otherwise is commented out by the `#` sign.

```
#EXTRA_GROUPS="dialout cdrom floppy audio video plugdev users"
```

Remove the comment sign `#` and edit the desired groups to change the default.

Comment: I edited this, still when I login with an active directory account, the user is only in the domain users group (which is the primary group of the user in the windows active directory)

Comment: You wrote " I mean if a user logs in for the first time (or if a user is created), he is automatically added to groups X, Y and Z for example". Only on creation, the groups are set. You need to change, a single time, the groups for each user that already exists. So I answered to what you asked in the body of your question, not to the question what happens with already existing users.